# Matries inequality with norms

Tags: matrices, inequality, operator-theory, normed-spaces, functional-inequalities

Let $P$ and $C \neq0$ a $q \times q$ matrices. I want to prove that there exists a positive constants $\alpha$ such under some assumptions under $P$ we have the inequality 
$${\left\| {P\left( {I - C} \right)x} \right\|_{{{\mathbb{R}}^q}}} \leqslant \alpha {\left\| {PCx} \right\|_{{{\mathbb{R}}^q}}}$$ for all $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$
whith $I$ is the identity matrix.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you expect such an inequality to hold? Could you give us a bit more context?

Comment: I need this inequality to prove the controllability of some system of PDE. I have to get rid of the R.H.S of the inequality.

Comment: I would suggest that you post a question about the actual system of PDE.  As your question stands, it is difficult to know what kind of conditions on $P$ we should be looking for.

Comment: I think that there is no relation between the inequality and the PDE problem. It is just a matrices inequality.

Comment: Wa can observe that a necessary condition is that the kernel of C is contained in the Kernel of P. Can we prove that it is also a sufficiant  condition?

Comment: Your inequality will be true for some $\alpha > 0$ if and only if $\ker(P(I - C)) \subseteq \ker(PC)$.  I don't believe that $\ker(C) \subseteq \ker(P)$ will be a sufficient condition to guarantee this.

Comment: For instance: your condition cannot hold for
$$
C = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}, \quad P = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}
$$
even though we have $\ker(C) \subseteq \ker(P)$

Comment: @Omnomnomno Thanks. But in your example wa have $I-C=0$ and the inequality is satisfied.Can you give me some hints to prove the statement.

Answer (score 0):

If $P=I$ and $C=0$, then there is no such positive constant, so that the inequality holds.

Comment: Thank tou for the remark, yes, the inequality does'nt hold for any $P$, I want to find some conditions on $P$ so that the inequality is satisfied.

Comment: I have changed the statement. Thank you for the remark.