# $\operatorname{Ker}(B) \subset \operatorname{Ker(A)}$ if and only if ${\left\| {Ax} \right\|_X} \leqslant \alpha {\left\| {Bx} \right\|_X}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Is this statement is correct: 
Let $X$ be a Banach space, and let $A$ and $B$ two continuous operators on $X$ , do we have for some constant $\alpha$ the following $${\left\| {Ax} \right\|_X} \leqslant \alpha {\left\| {Bx} \right\|_X} \Leftrightarrow \operatorname{Ker}(B) \subset \operatorname{Ker}(A)$$.
Thank you.

Comment: I believe that the inclusion should be reversed: If $x\in \ker B$, then $\Vert Ax \Vert \leq \alpha \Vert Bx \Vert = 0,$ so $Ax = 0$ and $x \in \ker A$, i.e. $\ker B \subset \ker A$.

Comment: Thanks. I will edit the statement. is it a sufficient and necessary condition?

Comment: Consider two injective operators for the reverse statement.

Comment: @BartoszMalman so it is correct. What about that, is there any difference?  thank you sir.https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3013126/matries-inequality-with-norms/3013131#3013131

Comment: @Gustave I don't think the implication holds. If it did, that would mean for any two operators with the same kernel the quantities $\|Ax\|$ and $\|Bx\|$ are comparable uniformly for $x \in X$. Such a thing certainly does not hold.

Comment: @BartoszMalman Thank you sir for the response. I just need to check that the inequality in the link holds (in finite dimension) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3013126/matries-inequality-with-norms/3013131#3013131

Answer (score 1):

In finite dimensions, it should be true. Let us denote by $R$ the range of $B$ and by $S$ the range of $A$. Then, you can define the linear operator
$$A \, B^{-1} : R \to S.$$
Due to the assumptions on the kernels, this operator is well defined and linear. Thus, it is continuous, i.e., there is $\alpha \ge 0$ with
$$ \|A \, B^{-1} y \| \le \alpha \, \|y\| \qquad\forall y \in R.$$
Now, setting $y = B \, x$ yields the claim.

Comment: Thanks. But How did you know that $B$ is invertible?

Comment: I do not use that $B$ is invertible. But for every $y \in R$, there exist at least one $x$ with $B \, x = y$ and the value of $A x$ is independent for all such $x$. Hence, you can define $(A B^{-1})(y) := A x$.

Comment: Thank you sir..

Comment: @daw: Ups. I removed this part of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

An example in the infinite-dimensional case can be constructed as follows: Let $A=Id$ and $B:X\to X$ compact and injective.  Thus $\ker A=\ker B$. If there would be
$\alpha>0$ such that $\|Ax\|=\|x\|\le \alpha \|Bx\|$ then the image of $B$ would be closed, thus $B$ would be bijective and continuously invertible, which is a contradiction.

An easy example is given by $X=l^2$ and
$$
Bx = (x_1,x_2/2,x_3/3,\dots,x_n/n,\dots).
$$
Here you could prove by hand that no such $\alpha$ exists (without recurring to compactness).

Comment: Thank you sir. For the prove of sir gerw it is not detailes, can you explain me why does he take the $B^{-1}$, and how the inclusion of kernels works because I have some confusion here. Thanks